# how to display the last mailchimp campaign?

Tags: views, blocks, emails

I need to display the last campaign (preview, description, name) in my website but currently mailchimp module doesn't have a block or view to do this, is there another alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I think you use mcc module for create mailchimp for node. when you disable this module its show list of all campaign which you created.

you can also use mailchimp function for getting list of campaign:

$campaigns = mailchimp_campaign_load_multiple();